# Python openpyxl load_workbook Errors: TypeError (NoneType not Iterable) and ValueError (Max. Value is 180)

Tags: python, windows, excel

So I had Python 3.4.1 installed on a Windows XP laptop. I got the openpyxl package (don't remember now which version, I think 2.1) and I was chugging along fine, writing custom code to modify Excel documents as needed at my workplace.

Then I formatted my laptop (for work-related reasons) and installed Windows 7. I got hold of Python 3.4.1 again. I pip installed openpyxl ("pip install openpyxl" in my command prompt) - definitely version 2.1 this time. I then tried opening some of my earlier workbooks.

**This was in the IDLE GUI interface - not in a script or anything.** I just typed (after properly importing openpyxl->load_workbook):

wb=load_workbook('Filename.xlsx')

And now I get errors. This file was created by Excel 2007 (created in Windows XP, prior to my formatting my laptop and installing Windows 7), which I was previously able to open just fine with my openpyxl package on my earlier Windows XP configuration. I also tried reopening the Excel file(s) in MS Excel (Windows 7) and resaving, before trying to open with openpyxl. Both my previous Windows XP and my new Windows 7 are 32 bit (no 64 bit anywhere).

The errors I get (depends on which file I try to open) are:

ERROR FOR FILE No. 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
wb=load_workbook('Filename.xlsx')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 151, in load_workbook
_load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 244, in _load_workbook
wb._external_links = list(detect_external_links(rels, archive))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\names\external.py", line 100, in detect_external_links
Book.links = list(parse_ranges(range_xml))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\names\external.py", line 85, in parse_ranges
for n in safe_iterator(names, '{%s}definedName' % SHEET_MAIN_NS):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

ERROR FOR FILE No. 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
wb=load_workbook('Filename.xlsx')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 151, in load_workbook
_load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 205, in _load_workbook
style_table, color_index, cond_styles = read_style_table(archive.read(ARC_STYLE))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 215, in read_style_table
p.parse()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 44, in parse
self.parse_cell_xfs()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 191, in parse_cell_xfs
_style['alignment'] = Alignment(**alignment)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 54, in __init__
self.textRotation = textRotation
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\hashable.py", line 54, in __setattr__
return object.__setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\__init__.py", line 89, in __set__
super(Min, self).__set__(instance, value)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\__init__.py", line 68, in __set__
raise ValueError('Max value is <0>'.format(self.max))
ValueError: Max value is 180
```

**For the second case, I went to the __init__.py file and added a line to print the value generated. It turned out to be 255, which is > 180 (hence the error). I have no clue what this value represents - number of unique styles in the document or something?**

Are there any dependencies for openpyxl? I have Excel properly installed (in Windows 7 now), with Service Pack 1. I have also tried uninstalling Python 3.4.1 and openpyxl and reinstalling, three or four times.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the `NoneType` error, clear the format of the data in the excel, then the excel could be loaded.

Comment: Simple though it probably is, consider clarifying _how_ you cleared the data's format in Excel to make your answer more complete.

Answer (score 0):

For the second, you have self.textRotation set to 255. That's where the max = 180 (degrees) comes from. In alignment.py, the min/max for textRoation is 0-180. This restriction was added in 2.1. (I find this restriction dubious, as there are 360 degrees.)

EDIT: In a more general sense, you're just trying to read an excel file. So, these are likely bugs.

Comment: OK, looks like the min/max for textRotation is fine, but Excel is reusing that field for a different style. If you create a book, select a cell, format cell, go to alignment, click the vertical "Text" in Orientation, (turning it white on black) then save, the resulting file cannot be opened in openpyxl, giving the same error you saw.

Comment: Created a bug report.

Comment: It could be the orientation. I'll give that a shot. In the meantime, I looked at what version of openpyxl was installed by my colleague. Turned out to be version 2.0.5. So I went back to that version (rather than 2.1.0), and now I don't have problems opening the same workbooks. Something went wrong with version 2.1.0? To check whether it's the alignment, I need to reinstall version 2.1.0 and try again. I'll do that and report back.

Comment: That's about what I thought. Still not sure what's with the first file; looks like an issue with links, though. Any weird links in that file?

Comment: I actually deleted the links in my Excel document. Searched manually for any links in cells or named ranges. Also used the document inspector to find any comments, personal data, headers and footers, custom xml data, etc. Deleted all those as well. Then saved the Excel file and retried openpyxl. (This was with version 2.1.0, before I uninstalled it to install version 2.0.5. Version 2.0.5 works in any case.). Version 2.1.0 still didn't work at the time. I haven't had a chance to reinstall version 2.1.0 of openpyxl yet, to try messing with the text alignment. Hopefully today.