# What does the error "Max value is 52" mean in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to load an Excel workbook into python using openpyxl's load_workbook() function but when the code gets to that line it throws an error which states "ValueError: Max value is 52".

This is the line that breaks the code:

`certifGenerator = openpyxl.load_workbook(generatorFileName, keep_vba = True)`

I have tried searching online but can't find anything regarding this issue.

Comment: It's probably some kind of formatting issue, though what exactly it is I'm not sure, you might be able to tell from the traceback. Some causes I've seen are too many comment boxes, rotated text and obscene numbers of sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Relevant maybe dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236928/openpyxl-valueerror-max-value-is-14-when-using-load-workbook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816796/what-does-this-python-openpyxl-valueerror-mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983420/python-openpyxl-load-workbook-errors-typeerror-nonetype-not-iterable-and-valu

Comment: Please include the complete traceback.